# Notation in defining the abstract tensor product

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

In John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold (chapter 12, page 308), the tensor product of $V_{1},\ldots,V_{n}$ is defined to be the quotient space $\mathcal{F}(V_{1}\times\ldots\times V_{n})/\mathcal{R}$, where $\mathcal{F}(V_{1}\times\ldots\times V_{n})$ is the free vector space and $\mathcal{R}$ is its subspace spanned by $\left(v_1, \ldots, a v_i, \ldots, v_k\right)-a\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i, \ldots, v_k\right)$ and $\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i+v_i^{\prime}, \ldots, v_k\right)-\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i, \ldots, v_k\right)-\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i^{\prime}, \ldots, v_k\right)$.

I am confused about these two sets of vectors. Are $a\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i, \ldots, v_k\right) = \left(av_1, \ldots, av_i, \ldots, av_k\right)$ and $\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i+v_i^{\prime}, \ldots, v_k\right)-\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i, \ldots, v_k\right)-\left(v_1, \ldots, v_i^{\prime}, \ldots, v_k\right) = \left(-v_1, \ldots,0,\ldots, -v_k\right)$? Moreover, what is the intuition behind defining this quotient space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have two different kinds of vector spaces, the free product and the actual product.

Let $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ be a collection of $n$ (real) vector spaces. We can form the product vector space

$$
V_1\times\cdots\times V_n
$$

Elements here look like

$$
(v_1,\ldots,v_n),\;\; v_i\in V_i.
$$

Now, we have the vector space operations given by component-wise addition and scalar multiplication

\begin{align*}
(v_1,\ldots,v_n)+(u_1,\ldots,u_n)&=(v_1+u_1,\ldots,v_n+u_n), \\
\alpha(v_1,\ldots,v_n)&=(\alpha v_1,\ldots,\alpha v_n).
\end{align*}

We can also construct the free vector space

$$
\mathcal{F}(V_1\times\cdots\times V_n).
$$

Elements here look like

$$
\sum_{i=1}^\ell\alpha_i w_i,
$$

where each $w_i$ is in the product (of sets) $V_1\times\cdots\times V_n$, i.e., $w_i=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. However, the vector space operations are now "formal"

\begin{align*}
(v_1,\ldots,v_n)+(u_1,\ldots,u_n)&\neq(v_1+u_1,\ldots,v_n+u_n), \\
\alpha(v_1,\ldots,v_n)&\neq(\alpha v_1,\ldots,\alpha v_n).
\end{align*}

It's like we forget that the product of vector spaces exists, so in the free vector space, we don't have these component-wise operations.

Consider the subset $\mathcal{R}$ of the free vector space generated by the following kinds of things

\begin{align*}
&(v_1,\ldots,\alpha v_i,\ldots,v_n)-\alpha(v_1,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_n), \\
&(v_1,\ldots,v_i+u_i,\ldots,v_n)-(v_1,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_n)-(v_1,\ldots,u_i,\ldots,v_n).
\end{align*}

In the free vector space these expressions are just formal. We cannot simplify them using component-wise operations. However, we want to go to a vector space where we can simplify those kinds of things. So we define the tensor product as the quotient space

$$
V_1\otimes\cdots\otimes V_n=\mathcal{F}(V_1\times\cdots\times V_n)/\mathcal{R}.
$$

In the tensor product we have vectors such as this

$$
v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n. 
$$

Note that since we are in a quotient space, the above vector is actually an equivalence class. Since the tensor product is a vector space, we have scalar multiplication

$$
\alpha(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n)
$$

However, by the relations in $\mathcal{R}$, this vector is equivalent to another vector, as follows

$$
\alpha(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n)=(\alpha v_1)\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n=\cdots=v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes(\alpha v_i)\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n=v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes(\alpha v_n).
$$

Similarly, if we have a vector of the form

$$
v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_i+u_i\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n,
$$

it is equivalent to the sum of vectors

$$
v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_i\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n+v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes u_i\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n.
$$

Now, for the intuition into why we define the tensor product. Suppose we had any map

$$
L:V_1\times\cdots\times V_n\to X,
$$

from the product of vector spaces to some vector space $X$, such that the map was multilinear. By this, I mean $L$ is linear in each argument when we hold every other argument constant:

$$
L(v_1,\ldots,\alpha v_i+\beta u_i,\ldots,v_n)=\alpha L(v_1,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_n)+\beta L(v_1,\ldots,u_i,\ldots,v_n).
$$

Then there exists a unique linear map

$$
\tilde{L}:V_1\otimes\cdots\otimes V_n\to X
$$

such that $\tilde{L}\circ q=L$, where $q$ is the map

$$
q(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n.
$$

(Note that $q$ is a multilinear map). Furthermore, the tensor product is the unique such vector space with this property, i.e., it is characterized by the property.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate with a simple example, let's take $n=2$ and $V_1=V_2=\mathbb{R}$.

Then $F=\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})$ is the space of formal finite linear combinations of pairs of real numbers. In this space, distinct pairs behave like unrelated elements (symbols) which are linearly independent. For example, the formal linear combinations
$$(0,3)-(0,1)-(0,2)\tag{1}$$
and
$$(0,2)-2\cdot(0,1)\tag{2}$$
are *not* equal to zero! Similarly
$$(1,2)-(1,1)\ne(0,1)\tag{3}$$
Intuitively, the pairing operation here should be viewed as a kind of "product" operation, where $(1,2)$ is the "product" of $1$ and $2$, and so on.

For the tensor product, we want the product operation to be *bilinear* (that is, linear in each factor) so in particular we want
$$0\otimes 3-0\otimes 1-0\otimes 2=0$$
and
$$0\otimes 2-2\cdot(0\otimes 1)=0$$
and
$$1\otimes 2-1\otimes 1=1\otimes 1$$
and so on.

We can achieve this by starting with the free space $F$ and "killing off" (forcing equal to zero) all vector combinations like those in (1) and (2) (and other similar ones) by taking the quotient by the subspace generated by them. In general, intuitively, taking a quotient by a subspace kills off the vectors in the subspace while preserving vector space structure. The pair "product" operation becomes the tensor product. Formally, if $\pi:F\to F/R$ is the quotient projection, then
$$v\otimes w=\pi(v,w)$$

Importantly, in this construction we only kill off the vectors required to make the tensor product operation bilinear, nothing more. For this reason intuitively the tensor product $\mathbb{R}\otimes\mathbb{R}$ is the "largest" or "most general" space in which we have a bilinear product on $\mathbb{R}$. This statement can be made precise in terms of the universal property of the tensor product.

(Note $\mathbb{R}\otimes\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}$ since the tensor product is equivalent to the scalar product in this case, but I wanted to keep the example simple, and these ideas generalize.)